# How to remove empty rows from an Pyspark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am having few empty rows in an RDD which I want to remove. How can I do it?

I tried the below but it is not working. I am still getting the empty rows

```
json_cp_rdd = xform_rdd.map(lambda (key, value): get_cp_json_with_planid(key, value)).filter(
            lambda x: x is not None).filter(
            lambda x: x is not '')
```

> [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'[{ "PLAN_ID": "d2031aed-175f-4346-af31-9d05bfd4ea3a",
>   "CostTotalInvEOPAmount": 0.0, "StoreCount": 0, "WeekEndingData":
>   "2017-07-08", "UnitTotalInvBOPQuantity": 0.0, "PriceStatus": 1,
>   "UnitOnOrderQuantity": null, "CostTotalInvBOPAmount": 0.0,
>   "RetailSalesAmount": 0.0, "UnitCostAmount": 0.0, "CostReceiptAmount":
>   0.0, "CostSalesAmount": 0.0, "UnitSalesQuantity": 0.0, "UnitReceiptQuantity": 0.0, "UnitTotalInvEOPQuantity": 0.0,
>   "CostOnOrderAmount": null}]', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'',
>   u'']

Comment: can you add schema for `xform_rdd.map(lambda (key, value): get_cp_json_with_planid(key, value))` ?

Comment: I am not sure @mrsrinivas if that can be done in the rdd. I can do it while converting it later into a DF

Comment: mark your answer as the problem resolved.

Comment: seems i can't accept it as solved  before 2 days

Comment: ok. accept it once 2 days over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replaced `filter(lambda x: x is not '')` with `filter(lambda x: x is not u'')` and it worked out

Answer (score 17):

`is` checks object identity not equality. In Python 2.x you could  use `!=`

```
.filter(lambda x: x is not None).filter(lambda x: x != "")
```

but idiomatically you can use only a single `filter` with identity:

```
.filter(lambda x: x)
```

or directly with [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#bool):

```
.filter(bool)
```